# Filter post by current 2 differents users id

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, author, plugin-list-category-post

I'm filtering my custom post type based on author. I want all users to be able to:
1 - in the list everyone can see the posts created by the admin.
2 - users can also see their own posts in the list, but not those of other users.

I can list by admin id only or current user id only, but not both.
Code:

```
function list_cpt_by_author_id(){
    $user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());
   
$authors_id = array(
    array('author' => "1"),
    array('author' => "$user"),
);
    
    $custom_terms = get_terms('custom-tax');
        foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
            wp_reset_query();
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'artigos',
                'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'custom-tax','field' => 'slug','terms' => $custom_term->slug,),),
                $authors_id,);
    
    
             $loop = new WP_Query($args);
             $image = get_field( 'cat_imagem', $custom_term );
    
             //Taxonomies Loop
             if($loop->have_posts()) {
                echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';
                echo '<img src="'.$image.'"/>';
                
                //Post loop
                while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';
                endwhile;
             }
            wp_reset_postdata(); // reset global $post;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone give me any tips?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @ali Sh help  I did: `'author' => $adm_u_id .',' . $u_id_c`

`$adm_u_id` so I can list any future editor ids and `$u_id_c` to list the userid of the current user.

Comment: Just a sidenote: You shouldn't (need to) call `wp_reset_query()`, only the `wp_reset_postdata()` that is necessary.

Comment: Oh! Nice. Ty again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on wordpress reference for [WP_QUERY](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#author-parameters) you can use *author__in* to filter by more than one author. It uses an array of user ids. Here is your code with the needed changes:

```
function list_cpt_by_author_id(){
    $user = get_current_user_id();
   
$authors_id = array("1", $user);

    
    $custom_terms = get_terms('custom-tax');
        foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
            wp_reset_query();
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'artigos',
                'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'custom-tax','field' => 'slug','terms' => $custom_term->slug,),),
                'author__in' => $authors_id,
            );
    
    
             $loop = new WP_Query($args);
             $image = get_field( 'cat_imagem', $custom_term );
    
             //Taxonomies Loop
             if($loop->have_posts()) {
                echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';
                echo '<img src="'.$image.'"/>';
                
                //Post loop
                while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';
                endwhile;
             }
            wp_reset_postdata(); // reset global $post;
        }
    }
```

P.S. I also found out that you are passing WP_USER object to $authors_id, but you only need the user's id.

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code - missing `array(` - `$authors_id = "1", "$user");`. Also, the `"$user"` could simply be written as `$user`..

Comment: @Ali Sh
Thank you very much there!
You've helped me a lot, especially recommending wp_query (How did I not just search for this? LOL)
  In the end I did:
`'author' => $adm_u_id .',' . $u_id_c`

`$adm_u_id` so I can list any future editor ids and `$u_id_c` to list the userid of the current user. Well you helped a lot. BTW Just need to fix a little syntax error in your answer.